# Javascript converts date with timezone MESZ to NaN

Tags: javascript

I came across this date string:

```
2017-08-19T11:54:00MESZ
```

When I attempt to convert it as follows, it returns NaN:

```
let date = Date.parse("2017-08-19T11:54:00MESZ");
```

It appears that the ending on this string isn't recognized.

Comment: Do not parse strings with Date.parse it is extremely unreliable, especially for non–standard strings . use a library like moment js

Comment: Am i wrong or are MES and Z*ulu* different timezones?

Comment: change "MESZ" to "+0200" first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format you're using is incorrect.

Take a look at this:

```
(new Date).toISOString()
"2017-08-19T10:05:18.700Z"
```

In contrast, the string you're trying to convert is:

"2017-08-19T11:54:00.MESZ"

`Date.parse` works with [a variant of ISO8601 or RFC2822](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse). Let's see how both options would work for you.

**Working with ISO**

It would accept either a UTC time zone descriptor ("Z") or a time zone offset ([read on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators)). Therefore the timezone instruction "MESZ" is invalid.

To reach a valid solution, you'd have to calculate the time zone offset from MESZ to Z, which is +2 hours, and append the the time expressed using wanted time zone:

```
Date.parse("2017-08-19T11:54:00+02:00")
1503136440000
```

**Working with RFC2822**

Example: "Mon, 25 Dec 1995 13:30:00 GMT"

Problem with RFC is that it [does not accept any other time zone than GMT, UTC and Pacific, Central, Eastern, Mountain times](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt) which is not really useful for you right now. You're left off with the same problem: you'd have to express the date with a time zone offset instruction:

```
Date.parse("Sat, 19 Aug 2017 11:54:00 +0200")
1503136440000
```

You're basically stuck with UTC, but frankly it's probably a good thing in many ways.